# Xcode warning - unable to build without warning

Tags: xcode

Can anyone tell me how to solve the following warning in Xcode?

```
"[WARN]Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'ShareKit-Info.plist'".
```

What's the problem in project?

Answer (score 2):

You are actually copying the plist to the bundle which should not be. Right click on the file and open Get Info, there should a Targets tab, have a look if it's checked. Uncheck.

You can also look in the targets Copy Bundle Resources phase and remove the plist there.

Here is an official [Technical Q&A from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1649/_index.html).